# Finding tensor of a matrix equation

Tags: matrix, tensors

I am trying to find the tensor, M for the following equation

$\rho' = M\cdot\rho$

where $\rho$ is a $n \times n$ matrix. How do I find the tensor $M$?

I tried changing $\rho$  into a column vector and used CoefficientArrays to extract the elements of tensor $M$ but this turned $M$ into $(n^2 \times n^2)$ matrix. I would like to keep $\rho$ as a $n \times n$ matrix.

I am solving this in the context of the quantum master equation where $\rho$ is the density matrix.

I am solving this for a two level system — $\rho$ is a $2*2$ matrix — for now, with plans to extend it to a four level one.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're asking. You can write `rho` as a column vector and `M` as an $n^2$ by $n^2$ matrix, as you said. But if you want to keep `rho` as a matrix, then the Lindbladian (and the Hamiltonian term for that matter) *can't* be represented as just a matrix. In general, you have terms of the form $a^{\dagger} \rho a$ in there that cannot be written in terms of direct matrix multiplication $M\rho$ for some $M$.

Comment: In any case, is this actually a question about the computing software *Mathematica*? If so, then we need more details about how you're coding things up. Please provide properly formatted, copy-and-paste-able *Mathematica* code in your post.

Comment: As @march says, this is mathematically not properly defined. An alternative interpretation of what you're trying to do is this: if $\rho$ is a member of an orthogonal basis of the matrix space, e.g. `PauliMatrix` in 2D, then you can find the expansion coefficients of $\rho'$ in that basis, and $M$ would be a vector of those coefficients. This would justify using the dot product, but then $M$ would multiply the vector of basis matrices, not just one of them.

Comment: I did some digging and the superoperator M can be expressed as a 2N-rank tensor i.e. for a 2x2 ρ, M would be a rank 4 tensor. I would need to somehow use TensorProduct and TensorContract function to make this work. I have yet to figure everything out, need more work on this.